# Set siunitx font size

Tags: fontsize, siunitx

I'm currently using

```tex
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-mode}
```

to place measurements with the same size of the surrounding text, but for dyslexic students, I would like to scale up measures. Is there a way to set the font size only for `\SI{}{}`, `\ang{}` and `\num{}` commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With v3, if you are happy to use text mode you can use the `text-font-command` key

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode = text, text-font-command = \Large}
\begin{document}
1234 \num{1234567890}
\end{document}
```